# How can I write a matrix to a temporary R object rather than to the hard disk drive?

Tags: r

I am programming a pipeline in R that makes use of a few packages from Bioconductor that require reading from a .FASTA file (which is essentially a custom formatted .txt file).

Right now I have a matrix that I write to a .FASTA file using a function such as:

```
exportFASTA(matrix, file = "directory\\sample.fasta")
```

Then, I run the algorithm on the file location:

```
algorithm(file = "directory\\sample.fasta")
```

I want to refine my code so that I do not have to write the file to the hard drive. Instead, I write the .FASTA (i.e. .txt file) to a temporary R object that R will interpret as if such a file exists on the hard drive.

Comment: See `?tempfile` perhaps?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I thought `tempfile` returned a character string with the name of a likely-unique filename in `tempdir`, which would be on the HDD.  Maybe in conjunction with a RAM disk tempdir....

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, yeah. I guess you're right. Haven't had my morning coffee yet.

Comment: Depending on why the OP wants to not use the hard drive, `tempfile` may still be good. If it's just to avoid hardcoding a path and filename, then `tempfile` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function `textConnection` that will process a character stream as if it were a file. Way back in the R 2.12 era (before the text= argument was introduced) one needed to use it to supply examples to read.table:

```
  >  read.table( file=textConnection("a b c\nd e f"), header=FALSE)
  V1 V2 V3
1  a  b  c
2  d  e  f
> txt <- "a b c\nd e f"
> read.table( file=textConnection(txt), header=FALSE)
  V1 V2 V3
1  a  b  c
2  d  e  f
```